# List directories in Azure Data Lake gen2 with hierarchical namespace

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am storing data on an Azure Datalake Gen2, with hierarchical namespace enabled. This enables me to create and rename directories, as in a traditional filesystem.

Is there any efficient way to list the sub-directories for a given directory? I can use the FileSystemClient.get_paths("my_directory"), but this method scans through all files and subdirectories under "my_directory".

Answer (score 0):

Using the recursive=False flag in the get_paths() method gets the job done.